# Using the " ' " mark as part of the data

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am trying to create an insert statements that will allow the " ' " mark to be used as data, and having problems finding a reference to it. My current statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO turnover(tail, discription, date) values ('$tail', '$discription', '$date')";
```

How ever when i put though this sample data i get:

```
INSERT INTO turnover(tail, discription, date) values ('173AB', 'No Dying MEL's tonight.', '05-14-2018')
```

If i remove the ' then it works fine. It seems i saw something a long time ago on it, but cannot find it.

Thanks in advance for any information that anyone can offer.

Comment: Is that PHP? If yes, add that tag. Is your problem the SQL itself? Add that tag. In any case, try to offload the burden of formatting the queries to code that is proven to not allow SQL injections.

Comment: In SQL server, double up every single quote to two quotes using a replace. I.e., ' becomes ''

Comment: @pixelda, that's also the ANSI/ISO SQL way to do it! (`... , 'No Dying MEL''s tonight.', ...`.

Comment: Every decent language these days (and many indecent ones!) should have a means for you to pass your SQL *code* and your *data*, separately. Usually, the data is passed using a mechanism called "parameters". If you're *merging* code and data by doing any kind of string interpolation/substitution then you're probably doing things wrong. When the data is passed separately from the code, `'`s in the data have *no special meaning*.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+escape+single+quote)  for many, many answers to the direct problem. But the correct solution is to use some kind of "prepared statement" - how you do that depends on the programming language you are using

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: **Use prepared statements**. Asuming you are using PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Alternatively you would apply some sort of escaping, like [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Take care not to mix PDO and MySQLi functions, and do not in any case use `mysql_*()` functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO turnover(tail, discription, date) values ('173AB', 'No Dying MEL''s tonight.', '05-14-2018')
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations to your answer. Furthermore, your answer does not cover the fact that the OP uses variables to store the values and may not be able to manually add the quotation mark.